# Pass params in reframe subscriptions to a chain function clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

```
(re-frame/reg-sub
 ::current-effects-list
 (fn [[_ effect-type]]
   [(re-frame/subscribe [::available-effects])
    effect-type])
 (fn [[available-effects effect-type]]
   (filter (fn [{:keys [text value selected? type]}]
             (= effect-type type))
           available-effects)))
```

I want to pass the param **effect-type** to the next chain function as an argument, but I am new at Clojure, thus the **effect-type** is coming as null in the second chain function.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```clj
(re-frame/reg-sub
 ::current-effects-list
 (fn [[_ effect-type]]
   (re-frame/subscribe [::available-effects])) ; there is no need to return effect-type from here
 (fn [available-effects [_ effect-type]]
   (filter (fn [{:keys [text value selected? type]}]
             (= effect-type type))
           available-effects)))
```